# Route path for different api version in zend framework 3

Tags: php, zend-framework3, zend-route

This is how I defined route for my api. It is prefixed with /api/v1. But now few new modules are added in api v2 and all v1 apis are remains same and available in v2. How can i modify this routes that will serve all routes belongs to /api/v1 and when /api/v1 is called and it should serve both /api/v2 and /api/v1 when /api/v2 is called?

module.config.php

```
'product' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Router\Http\Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/api/v1/categories[/:id]',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => CategoryController::class,
        ),
    ),
),
'products' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Router\Http\Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/api/v1/products[/:id]',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => ProductsController::class,
        ),
    ),
),

// ... at lots of v1 apis

//these are introduced in v2
'trends' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Router\Http\Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/api/v2/trends[/:id]',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => TrendsController::class,
        ),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move those common `v1` and `v2` to a single parent route and `v2`-only ones to another. Below is sample (not tested) code that should help you understand the idea.

```
return [
    // in Config.router.routes
    'api' => [
        'child_routes' => [
            'v1' => [
                'child_routes' => [
                    // your API 1-and-2 routes
                    'product' => [/* … */],
                    'products' => [/* … */]
                ],
                'may_terminate' => false,
                'options' => [
                    'constraints' => ['version' => 'v1|v2'],
                    'route'       => '/:version'
                ],
                'type' => Segment::class
            ],
            'v2' => [
                'child_routes' => [
                    // your API 2 routes
                    'trends' => [/* … */]
                ],
                'may_terminate' => false,
                'options' => ['route' => '/v2'],
                'type' => Literal::class
            ]
        ],
        'may_terminate' => false,
        'options' => ['route' => '/api'],
        'type' => Literal::class
    ]
];
```

If you prefer to not use child routes, you can simply add a route parameter/constraint instead of `/v1`:

```
return [
    'product' => [
        'options' => [
            'constraints' => [
                'id'      => '…',
                'version' => 'v1|v2'
            ],
            'defaults' => ['controller' => CategoryController::class],
            'route' => '/api/:version/categories[/:id]'
        ],
        'type' => Segment::class
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but I just found this question.

Whilst @gsc's answer is somewhat ok, this is not the correct answer.

This is the correct answer, and this is how I use it:

```
            'api' => [
            /** Our main route is /api **/
            'may_terminate' => true, 
            'options' => ['route' => '/api'],
            'type' => Literal::class, 
            'child_routes' => [
                /** Since our main route is /api, this will become /api/v1/YOUR_ACTIONS **/
                'v1' => [
                    'type'    => Segment::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'route'    => '/v1[/:action]',
                        'constraints' => [
                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ],
                        'defaults' => [
                            'controller'    => Controller\ApiV1Controller::class,
                            'action'        => 'index',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                 /** Since our main route is /api, this will become /api/v2/YOUR_ACTIONS **/
                'v2' => [
                    'type'    => Segment::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'route'    => '/v2[/:action]',
                        'constraints' => [
                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ],
                        'defaults' => [
                            'controller'    => Controller\ApiV2Controller::class,
                            'action'        => 'index',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                /** Add as many "versions" as you want, all with different controllers. **/
            ],
        ],
```

This allows you to use different "versions" of your controller and is shorter, better understandable and complies to standards.

Enjoy!